# SIFT clustering converting sift features (128 dimensional vector) into a vocabulary

Tags: opencv, image-processing, classification, sift

How to cluster the extracted SIFT descriptors. The aim of doing clustering is to use it for classification purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cluster , convert N*128 dimension(N is the number of descriptor from each image) into a array of M*128 dimension (M number of descriptor from all images). and perform cluster on this data.

eg:

```
def dict2numpy(dict):
    nkeys = len(dict)
    array = zeros((nkeys * PRE_ALLOCATION_BUFFER, 128))
    pivot = 0
    for key in dict.keys():
        value = dict[key]
        nelements = value.shape[0]
        while pivot + nelements > array.shape[0]:
            padding = zeros_like(array)
            array = vstack((array, padding))
        array[pivot:pivot + nelements] = value
        pivot += nelements
    array = resize(array, (pivot, 128))
    return array

all_features_array = dict2numpy(all_features)
nfeatures = all_features_array.shape[0]
nclusters = 100
codebook, distortion = vq.kmeans(all_features_array,
                                         nclusters)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Approach:**

- First of all compute the `SIFT descriptor` for each image/object and then `push_back` that descriptor into a single image (lets called that image `Mat featuresUnclustered`).
- After that your task is to cluster all the descriptor into some number of groups/clusters (which is decided by you). That will be the size of your vocabulary/dictionary.

  `int dictionarySize=200;`
- And then finally comes the step of clustering them

  ```
  //define Term Criteria
  TermCriteria tc(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,100,0.001);

  //retries number
  int retries=1;

  //necessary flags
  int flags=KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;

  //Create the BoW (or BoF) trainer
  BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictionarySize,tc,retries,flags);

  //cluster the feature vectors
  Mat dictionary=bowTrainer.cluster(featuresUnclustered);
  ```

Comment: ok, how to represent descriptor for clustering, I know descriptor as 128 feature. so how to represent them

Comment: for one object/image you will get one descriptor which is nothing but an image with one row and 128 columns. So, if you use 50 images, then you will have 50 such images (i.e. with one row and 128 columns). Now, you put all of these rows in a Single image which featuresUnclustered` in my example above.

Answer (score -1):

usually [kmeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) is applied to get k centers,  you can change each image into a vector of the K (each dimension represent how many patch in that cluster).